# Swing+servlet connection

Tags: java, servlet, swing

Добрый день! Делаю swing - servlet connection. То есть через обычное десктопное приложение в сервлет передаются какие-то данные и эти же данные получает назад.

```
public class Demo
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    try
    {
        Test frame=new Test();
        frame.setSize(300,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());}
}
}
```

Класс Test

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JButton SUBMIT;
JPanel panel;
JLabel label1,label2;
final JTextField  text1,text2;
 URL u;
URLConnection uc;
DataOutputStream printout;
Test()
{
    label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setText("Input:");
    text1 = new JTextField(15);
    text2 = new JTextField(50);
    label2 = new JLabel();
    label2.setText("Output:");
    SUBMIT=new JButton("SUBMIT");

    panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(text1);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(text2);
    panel.add(SUBMIT);
    add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    SUBMIT.addActionListener(this);
    setTitle("I/O");
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
  onSendData();
}

private URLConnection getServletConnection()
    throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
String input = text1.getText();
    // Connection zum Servlet

    URL urlServlet = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SwingChat/MyServlet?");
    URLConnection con = urlServlet.openConnection();

    // konfigurieren
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestProperty(
        "Content-Type",
        "text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    // 
    return con;
}
 private void onSendData() {
    try {
        // get input data for sending
        String input = text1.getText();

        // send data to the servlet
        URLConnection con = getServletConnection();
        OutputStream outstream = con.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstream);
        oos.writeObject(input);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

        // receive result from servlet
        InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
        String result = (String) inputFromServlet.readObject();
        inputFromServlet.close();
        instr.close();

        // show result
        text2.setText(result);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        text2.setText(ex.toString());
    }
}

}
```

И сервлет

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      try {
        //response.setContentType("application/x-java-serialized-object");

        // read a String-object from applet
        // instead of a String-object, you can transmit any object, which
        // is known to the servlet and to the applet
        InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputFromSwing = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        String echo = (String) inputFromSwing.readObject();

        // echo it to the applet
        OutputStream outstr = response.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstr);
        oos.writeObject(echo);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Когда запускаю, выходит

```
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)          at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
```

Когда в браузере набираю "http://localhost:8080/SwingChat/MyServlet" ошибка ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved

Вот мой web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web- app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>SwingChat</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Что я делаю не так? Помогите. :(

Comment: с соединением все в порядке? 
попробуйте в браузере перейти по адресу "http://localhost:8080/SwingChat/MyServlet"

Comment: @lp_4eva, видимо у вас что то с сервером. 
Проверьте порт у сервера (сейчас он 8080). Также возможно у вас не сработала аннотация, лучше для начала задайте путь в сервлету через web.xml

Comment: @whispeer, порт 8080 свободен, а на счет файла web.xml, у меня нет такого файла о_О его надо создавать или он автоматом генерируется? Я собираю все в нетбинсе, там такого файла нет, помню, когда раньше писала в эклипсе, там у меня был такой файл, а в нетбинсе нет.
@whispeer, тип проекта java web-веб приложение. Папка WEB-INF у меня пустая.

Comment: @lp_4eva, когда создавали проект, какой тип проекта вы выбирали? 
посмотрите в папке WEB-INF

Comment: @lp_4eva, довольно странно, там должен быть файл web.xml , если его никто не удалял или перемещал. 
А само приложение нормально разворачивается? Нет ошибок в логах "Apache Tomcat" ?

Comment: @whispeer, томкат вообще выключенный, он у меня запускается вообще без томката. Я его включила и запустила, все то же самое. Если запустить проект в целом, то сразу выходит автоматом созданный проектом index.html файл и томкат автоматический включается, но мой demo.java не запускается, поэтому я demo.java отдельно запускаю.

Comment: потому что твой томкан, запущенный из netbeans'a, запускается с совершенно другими настройками.

Comment: В общем, я прочла, что ниже какой-то версий Нетбинса там нет файла web.xml и этот файл можно создавать вручную. Так и сделала, не помогло:( 
@argamidon, какими другими настройками? Что надо сделать, не подскажите?

Comment: залезть в настройки нетбинса, открыть вкладку с настройками серверов. там увидиш пару ссылок путей. в них хранятся настройки томката с которыми их запускает неибинс

Comment: @argamidon,я знаю как менять настройки томкат, я имела в виду зачем их менять, если они запускаются без ошибки в логах? Просто в моем проекте они не используются, то есть используются когда запускаю общий проект и открывается пустой сгенерированный index.html файл. Но этот файл мне вообще не нужен, поэтому я запускаю свой demo.java файл чтобы тот запустил test.java. Ему то здесь не нужен томкат?